# Mongoose update nested objects on multiple documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is the schema:

```
var user = new Schema ({
    name: {type:String},
    lastName:  {type:String},
    extraInfo: {
        phone: {type:String},
        age: {type: Number}
    },
    postalCode: {type:Number}
})
```

Let's assume we have 10 documents with that schema and 5 of them have postalCode '12345'.

How can I select all of them and update the extraInfo.phone and extraInfo.age of these documents?

Comment: Do you want to update all matching documents with the same values?

Comment: Yes, all matching same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i dont have a database at hand, to try it out, but it should be something like this.

```
db.User.update(
    {postalCode: 12345}, 
    {"extraInfo.phone": value1, "extraInfo.age": value2},
    {multi: true});
```

Comment: I've already tried that before, my mistake was the " instead of ' in properties. How dumb I didnt tried that... Thanks.

the whole code in express/mongoose should be:
`User.update(
    {postalCode: 12345}, 
    {"extraInfo.phone": value1, "extraInfo.age": value2},
    {multi: true}).exec( function (err, response) {
    if(err){
    console.log(err) // or send a 500 status
    }
     if(response){
res.status(200).json(response)
}`